# Из колонок в карусель bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Имеется сетка, как при экране для мобильных сделать карусель, а не выстраивать в одну колонку?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="couresel">
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="kartinka">
          <img src="">
         </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="kartinka">
          <img src="">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="kartinka">
          <img src="">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я нашел такой выход:

```
    function changeLayout(){
    var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
    var children = carousel.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var length = children.length;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if(w < 600){
        carousel.className = 'carousel-inner';
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                children[i].className = 'item active';
                continue;
            }
            children[i].className = 'item';
        }
        $('#carousel').carousel({interval:4500});
    }
    else{
        carousel.className = 'row'; 
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            children[i].className += 'col-md-4';        
        }
    }
}
```

но у меня возникла проблема, он `class="kartinka"` заменяет на `col-md-4`, а надо чтобы было `class="kartinka col-md-4"`, как так сделать?

Comment: в данном случае дивы не должны выстраиваться в одну колонку. Они должны находиться в одной строке.

Comment: при разрешении экрана < 768 они выстраиваются в одну колонку

Answer (score -1):

Ну так допишите в скрипте `children[i].className += 'kartinka col-md-4';`